# Monit: В лог пишет failed cannot open a connection to inet

Tags: node.js, nginx, monit

Развернул проект на node.js, подключил его к nginx, далее установил ustart для запуска проекта и monit для контроля.
В конфиге monit (etc/monit/monitrc) прописал следующее:

```
set logfile /var/log/monit.log

check process nodejs with pidfile "/var/run/prog.pid"
    start program = "/sbin/start prog"
    stop program  = "/sbin/stop prog"
    if failed port 8000 protocol HTTP
        request /
        with timeout 10 seconds
        then restart
```

Затем запустил проект

```
start prog
monit - d 60   - c /etc/monit/monitrc
```

В prog.pid записался хеш, вроде бы все гут, а вот в лог постоянно пишет следующее

```
[MSK Jun 21 12:53:09] info     : monit: generated unique Monit id 2a1de02cb335c0b2f136409391c852d5 and stored to '/root/.monit.id'
[MSK Jun 21 12:53:09] info     : Starting monit daemon
[MSK Jun 21 12:53:09] info     : 'p215721' Monit started
[MSK Jun 21 12:53:09] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 12:53:09] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 12:53:09] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 12:53:10] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 12:54:11] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 12:54:11] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 12:54:11] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 12:54:12] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 12:55:13] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 12:55:13] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 12:55:13] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 12:55:14] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 12:56:15] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 12:56:15] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 12:56:15] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 12:56:16] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 12:57:17] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 12:57:17] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 12:57:17] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 12:57:18] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 12:58:19] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 12:58:19] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 12:58:19] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 12:58:20] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 12:59:21] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 12:59:21] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 12:59:21] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 12:59:22] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:00:23] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:00:23] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:00:23] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:00:24] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:01:18] info     : Awakened by User defined signal 1
[MSK Jun 21 13:01:18] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:01:18] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:01:18] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:01:18] info     : monit daemon at 25858 awakened
[MSK Jun 21 13:01:19] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:02:20] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:02:20] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:02:20] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:02:21] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:03:22] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:03:22] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:03:22] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:03:23] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:04:24] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:04:24] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:04:24] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:04:25] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:05:26] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:05:26] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:05:26] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:05:27] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:06:28] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:06:28] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:06:28] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:06:29] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:07:30] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:07:30] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:07:30] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:07:31] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:08:32] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:08:32] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:08:32] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:08:33] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:09:34] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:09:34] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:09:34] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:09:35] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:10:36] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:10:36] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:10:36] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:10:37] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:11:38] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:11:38] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:11:38] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:11:39] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:12:40] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:12:40] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:12:40] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:12:41] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:13:42] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:13:42] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:13:42] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:13:43] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:14:44] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:14:44] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:14:44] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:14:45] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:15:46] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:15:46] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:15:46] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:15:47] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
[MSK Jun 21 13:16:49] error    : 'nodejs' failed, cannot open a connection to INET[localhost:8000] via TCP
[MSK Jun 21 13:16:49] info     : 'nodejs' trying to restart
[MSK Jun 21 13:16:49] info     : 'nodejs' stop: /sbin/stop
[MSK Jun 21 13:16:50] info     : 'nodejs' start: /sbin/start
```

Может быть с этим связано:
Проект на node.js использует порт 8124

И еще вопрос между делом как остановить monit или перезапустить его.

Comment: @webphp, постарайтесь в следующий раз не постить повторяющиеся куски лога

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже в порте было дело, указал порт 8124 в конфиге monit, убил процесс и запустил заново. Сейчас уже как 10 минут молчит и ничего не пишет в log